# Why "&" is adding while request in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

[http request default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX7SP.png) [http request config.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkWat.png) [csv data config used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGTvR.png) [csv data file used .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5S5z.png)I wanted to add data from csv file, but if i pass single parameter also its adding "&" character before parameter.
ex: https://www.linkedin.com/start/join?&name=A0A1A0

Comment: Can you share the CSV data set config which you are using ?

Comment: i have attached screenshot of csv file.

Comment: Can you also share the http request path as well in the question

Comment: http config. details added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove this `?` sign from the `/api/dealer/searchByPostalCode`

JMeter automatically detects [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) beginning in the [URL path](https://www.gilliganondata.com/index.php/2012/05/22/the-anatomy-of-a-url-protocol-hostname-path-and-parameters/) and tries to **merge** parameters with the ones you specify in the path to avoid syntax errors.

Given you don't provide any parameters in the "Path" section you should remove `?` from there.

[image]

---

Another possible reason is that your CSV data contains this `&` character, double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation:

> As a special case, the string "\t" (without quotes) in the delimiter
>   field is treated as a Tab.
>
> When the end of file (EOF) is reached, and the recycle option is true,
>   reading starts again with the first line of the file.

Source: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

So I'd request you to remove `\n` in delimiter field from the CSV Data set config and then try.

Comment: same problem after changing delimeter "," or "\t".

Comment: Don't use the delimiter value. Just remove and keep it blank.

Comment: problem happening because of parameter. if i put parameter value as A0A0A0 also its adding "&".  https://dev.testapi/api/searchByPostalCode?&postalCode=A0A0A0

Comment: Please try changing your path to 
`/api/dealer/searchByPostalCode?postalCode=${postalCode}` in the HTTP Request settings. Also, make column name in excel sheet is same as postalCode.

Comment: Great let me know which part exactly helped and I'll update the answer. Please mark this answer as best and upvote, if it has helped.